# Getting clicked label's text using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery.live() functionality to trap click event of any label in a `<div>`. But when clicked, I want to get the text of the clicked label. I tried `$(this).text`, but it displays the entire code.

Comment: Do you have nested elements inside the labels ?

Comment: No, I don't have nested elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).text` returns the code of the function named `text`.

You have to CALL the method, using:

- `var myText = $(this).text();` to get the text or:
- `$(this).text('some text');` to set it

Answer (score 3):

Add parenthesis to use the method.

This will get the text.

```
$(this).text()
```

This will set it.

```
$(this).text("New Text")
```

[text() in the jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Text%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

$(this).val() should get the input value.

Comment: I used the above code in alert(), and it is showing blank text.